# Getting 'type' of a View's model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

you can access View's model from the View methods - like `render()` (through its `model` property). But let's say you have many different models and use the them with the same type of View, changing view's `model` property when you need.

How can you determine from the View what type of the model it's using?

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Model2 = Backbone.Model.extend();

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render:function(){
    console.log(" you're using: "+ model); // how to determine here is it using Model1 or Model2
  }
})

var mv1 = new MyView({model: new Model1()})
var mv2 = new MyView({model: new Model2()})
```

Comment: Would this help? (I assume you're looking for something like "typeof"...) http://jsbin.com/emeyay/1/edit

Comment: @Dashk yes... please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping this simple...

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Model2 = Backbone.Model.extend();

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render:function(){
    if (this.model instanceof Model1) {
      alert("You're using model1");
    }
    else if (this.model instanceof Model2) {
      alert("You're using model2");
    }
    else {
      alert("I've no idea what you're using");
    }
  }
})

var mv1 = new MyView({model: new Model1()});
var mv2 = new MyView({model: new Model2()});
mv1.render();
mv2.render();
```

Comment: The key word here is "many". With *many* different models, this "simple" approach becomes impractical.  Because not only you have to add a branch for each new model type, but also you have to put them in the right order, so that "subclasses" always come before "superclasses".

Answer (score 2):

**Objects have identity, not name.**  If you want to know the name of the constructor that created an object (which can be considered the object's type; see [the ECMAScript Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15)), the bullet-proof approach is to make that information part of the constructed object:

```
var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend({type: "Model1"});
var Model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({type: "Model2"});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {
    console.log("You are using " + this.model.type);
  }
});

var mv1 = new MyView({model: new Model1()});
var mv2 = new MyView({model: new Model2()});
```

This way, the model objects inherit the `type` property through the prototype chain. See also http://backbonejs.org/#View-render.

Alternative, less efficient and less reliable solutions include:

- Giving the constructor a name and accessing that:

  ```
  var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend();
  Model1.name = "Model1";

  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
      console.log("You are using " + this.model.constructor.name);
    }
  });

  var mv1 = new MyView({model: new Model1()});
  var mv2 = new MyView({model: new Model2()});
  ```

  (The additional assignment to the `name` property was not necessary if the constructor was

  ```
  var Model1 = function Model1 () {
    // …
  };
  ```

  or

  ```
  function Model1 ()
  {
    // … 
  }
  ```

  but that is – unfortunately – not the Backbone.js way.)
- Parsing the string representation of a named `Function` instance such as a constructor.
  But that is implementation-dependent:

  ```
  var Model1 = function Model1 () {
    // …
  };

  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    getModelName: function () {
      var aFunction = this.model.constructor;
      return (aFunction != null && typeof aFunction.name != "undefined" && aFunction.name)
        || (String(aFunction).match(/\s*function\s+([A-Za-z_]\w*)/) || [, ""])[1];
    },

    render: function () {
      console.log("You are using " + this.getModelName());
    }
  });
  ```

  (Implemented as [jsx.object.getFunctionName()](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fobject.js). But again, AIUI not fully possible with Backbone.js.)
- Using `instanceof` as suggested in DashK's answer. But that does not give you information immediately or reliably.
  Because you have to put the most significant name in the prototype chain first, and change the method whenever you change the prototype chain, or you
  will get false positives and false negatives:

  ```
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
      var modelName = "an unknown model";

      if (this.model instanceof Model1)
      {
        modelName = "Model1";
      }
      else if (this.model instanceof Model2)
      {
        modelName = "Model2";
      }
      else if (this.model instanceof Supermodel)
      {
        modelName = "Supermodel";
      }

      console.log("You are using " + modelName);
    }
  });
  ```